# postgresql WAL file internals

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Actually I am using WAL files for designing a replication tool and I need to know if there is any method by which we can obtain sql statements executed in particular transaction id (xid)

Here is a block of information which I have from the processing of WAL file in pg_xlog directory...

```
INSERT INTO "16425" ([cur:0/192E8EAC, xid:1111, rmid:10(Heap), len:39/67, prev:0/112E8E68] insert: s/d/r:1663/16384/16425 blk/off:527/44 header: t_infomask2 3 t_infomask 2048 t_hoff 24
INSERT INTO "16425" ([cur:0/192E8EF0, xid:1111, rmid:10(Heap), len:39/67, prev:0/112E8EAC] insert: s/d/r:1663/16384/16425 blk/off:527/45 header: t_infomask2 3 t_infomask 2048 t_hoff 24
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not easily possible.  The WAL works at a much lower level.

There is work under way to do something like what you describe in PostgreSQL 9.3, but it is a very large project. Search the pgsql-hackers list for "logical replication" and "BDR" to learn more.

Comment: ok can you just tel me is there any meta data in postgresql for statements and transaction id so that i can extract data from there also, i know its tedious job

Comment: is there and method to reconstruct sql statements from reading the WAL file

Comment: You can try to extract some of the information from the textual server log, but it's not going to get you very far.

Comment: @user1802481 At the moment there's no reliable way to do what you want. Some new features - event triggers, logical replication, BDR, etc - are being worked on to handle it. In the mean time, check out Londiste, Bucardo and Slony-I.